# Api gives wrong response

Tags: ios, swift, api

I wrote an API manager using Alamofire in the following code and it works fine.

```
 func apiGet(url:String,parameters:[String:Any] , completion: @escaping (_ data:[String:Any]? , _ error:Error?) -> Void)
    {
        if UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible == true
        {
            let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
            manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120

            manager.request(url, method:.get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headersintoApi()).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false


                if response.result.isSuccess
                {
                    if let data = response.result.value as? [String:Any]
                    {
                        completion(data , nil)

                    }else{
                        Helper.Alertmessage(title: "Alert", message: (response.error?.localizedDescription)!, vc: nil)

                        completion(nil,response.error)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Helper.Alertmessage(title: "Alert", message: (response.error?.localizedDescription)!, vc: nil)
                    completion(nil,response.error)
                    print("App error mesage is: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                }
            }

        }else{
            Helper.Alertmessage(title: "Alert!", message: "Please Check Internet Connection", vc: nil)

        }
    }
```

but in some cases, API response comes in the form of [[String:Any]] and because of that, it crashes. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: You have to provide more information!
If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you.
Follow our [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and remember that our community is made possible by volunteers.

Comment: you can add an else if clause for handling the array of dictionaries case

Comment: It gives an error Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Any]]' to expected argument type '[String : Any]?'

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to the following to handle the case where you're getting an array of dictionaries in response

```
if let data = response.result.value as? [String:Any]
                    {
                        completion(data , nil)

                    }
else if let data = response.result.value as? [[String:Any]]
                    {
                        completion(data , nil)

                    }
else{
                        Helper.Alertmessage(title: "Alert", message: (response.error?.localizedDescription)!, vc: nil)

                        completion(nil,response.error)
                    }
```

Also keep the completion argument data of type  `Any?` in order to handle it properly.

Comment: This [[ ]] situation after we get data showing error.

Comment: @srikanth you need to provide more info than that provided in the question. Otherwise, it'd be shooting arrows in the dark. What is the response for instance at the moment you enter isSuccess code block?

Comment: In the second case you have an array of [String: Any], why not loop over that array?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think the response they're receiving is an array of blank dictionary. Read the first comment.

Comment: Well your code will never work if you call `completion` with a variable type that doesn't match the signature

Comment: That's right @JoakimDanielson, I thought that data was of type ````Any?````. Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: It gives an error Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Any]]' to expected argument type '[String : Any]?'

Comment: It is occurring at array of dictionaries case.